# Retrieving data from an asp page using jQuery's $.get ajax method

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp-classic, get

jQuery's `$.get` method should be an easy way of retrieving data generated by an .asp page running jscript, but so far I've not been able to make it work.

A model example from the jQuery documentation is

```
$.get("test.php", function(data){
    alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
});
```

But when I try using an asp page instead of the .php function I get nowhere.
My asp page:

```
<% response.write "Hello World" %>
```

My html page, apart from headers and src refs to jQuery, is simply

```
$.get("test.asp", function(data){
    alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
});
```

Loading the page results in a blank page.
Is there a reason why this can't happen, or have I just got it wrongly set up?

Comment: When you go to `test.asp` in the browser does it display Hello World on the page?

Comment: when you alert the data what do you see ?? please put your full jquery code

Comment: There's nothing special about the server-side technology that will prevent it from working. Have you tried adding error handing to the get or inspected the HTTP result via fiddler or your browsers development tools "network" diagnostics?

Comment: PHP or ASP is not very important, there are working the same way (there are difference but from a general point of view, not really). The server process the request, and output a response. Check your JS console and the network tabs in Firebug (if you are working with firefox) or Chrome

Comment: Hoping that you are running your page on IIS not directly the html page in the web browser

Comment: @sachileen  When I checked test.asp I found a missing % - embarassing. On fixing, worked fine. Thanks for everyones commments: which give confidence to continue this way.

Comment: Use firebug next time and you would have seen that 500 error :)